# Getting the year from a Date custom field

Tags: workflow, formula-field, datetime, date

I have a custom field whose data type is "Date". I would like to use this field in a formula editor. I want to get only the year value from the date field( field api name is `pres_date__c`). When I used the following it gave me a error that-

> pres_date__c may not be used in this type of formula

i) `YEAR(pres_date__c  )`
ii) `YEAR(DATE(pres_date__c))`

Both of the above did not give me an year value. Any suggestion how can I just get the year from date?

Comment: try `YEAR(DATEVALUE(pres_date__c))`

Comment: It gave me the same error..

Comment: Yes I am sure the data type is a date

Comment: what is your return type of formula

Comment: Yes your formula field return type should be integer

Comment: It is actually a text field type and I am using Formula editor to assign a text there. I tried using TEXT( pres_date__c ), but that too did not work and gave the same error that pres_date__c may not be used in this type of formula

Comment: @Rdvsm `pres_date__c` date type and your formula field return type is text ?

Comment: I have a field named date_text__c which is a text data type. In this text data type field I am using the formula editor to get the year from pres_date__c as TEXT. I am using the formula editor to set the value of date_text__c.

Comment: @Rdvsm if you need year from `pres_date__c` field then why you need `date_text__c` field ?

Comment: I need to use YEAR from pres_date__c to decide what text value will date_text__c get. If YEAR>2010 then date_text__c get "YES' else if YEAR<2010 then date_text__c  gets 'NO'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34617/discussion-between-ratan-and-rdvsm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I tested on Contact:

Formula return type: Text

```
TEXT(YEAR( Birthdate ))
```

That works.

I'd check that you really have a date field.

Comment: Can I use this TEXT(YEAR( Birthdate )) in a a field whose return type is Text ( is it possible to use this in the formula editor of text data type field)

Comment: Yes, that's how I did it in my test. If you use number Salesforce will try to be helpful and display "2,016". Probably not what you want.

Comment: I had to use a workflow field update for this. It did not work when using in normal text field-> default value-> formula.

Comment: There's a difference between creating a text field with a formula default value, and a formula field that contains text. A formula in a default value can't know about any other values for that record, since they don't yet exist. Therefore the formula editor only gives you access to global values.